# PHP date behaving incorrect

Tags: php

I don't know what I am missing but PHP's date function is behaving very incorrectly.

The date on my PC shows 26th October 2011, 11:32 AM but when I do:

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

I get `2011-10-26 06:02:28`

What is happening? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: What is your php.ini's timezone set to? Is PHP running on a server in a different timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change your `date.timezone` in php.ini.

Here's a list of the available [timezones for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Don't forget to restart your server after a new timezone is set.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with the time zone settings

try some thing like that

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
```